# what would be the function of a resistor 36,000 ohms across leads on non polarized electrolytic capacitors in a roto phase phase converter

Tags: phase

I have a surface grinder (3 phase) and believe that some of the capacitors are shot 
in my phase converter due to a lack of available surge power. The grinder starts and works ok but the circuit board for reversing the carriage shows an error(Red LED lit) intermittently and carriage does not reverse direction. Could be lots of things.(Already replaced circuit board and worked fine at first then similar problem of carriage reversing direction happened again. I can get it going if I push
it so I am thinking  because the converter is old and the capacitors don't cost too much I would replace them. However some the wire leads are soldered directly to the capacitor leads, and 2 of them have resistors soldered across the leads. Why are they there.

Comment: could be a bleeder, hard to tell from so little info

Comment: Welcome to the site.  How about a schematic, wiring diagram, part numbers, etc?

Answer (score 1):

As a safety measure, capacitors are expected to discharge to a safe voltage level (something like 50 volts or less) within a short time (something like 30 seconds or less). If the nature of the circuit is not sufficient to assure that, a bleeder resistor is connected across the capacitors.

Rather than repair a circuit by trial and error, it is better to have some understanding of the circuit and proceed based on analysis, measurements and tests.